# Why Java isnt calculating logical shift right correctly?

Tags: java, byte, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I just learned about logical shift right. Why my java isnt calculating it correctly?
Example:

```
public class Operators {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte z = -16;
        System.out.println((z >>> 2));
    }    
}
```

Why Java output: `1073741820`

```
-16 = 1111 0000
-16 >>> 2 = 0011 1100 = 60
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(z >>> 2));`

Comment: Did you expect `System.out.println((byte) (z >>> 2));` ?

Comment: Because byte, short and int all get operated on as int. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)

Comment: Questions like "why is Java wrong" are often med with negative reactions because it's perceived as somewhat mislead when an unwelcome behaviour is observed and it's assumed that the hundreds of engineers who built, tested and improved the base system are more likely to have made a basic, obvious mistake than that *you* made a mistake and/or misinterpreted something. Phrasing it like "Why isn't this behaving the way I expect it" the next time would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The unsigned right shift operator `>>>` do not use the sign bit to fill the trailing positions. It always fills the trailing positions by `0`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        byte z = -16;
        System.out.println("z in decimal: " + z + ",              binary: " + s.substring(Integer.toBinaryString(z).length())
                + Integer.toBinaryString(z));
        System.out.println("z >>> 1 in decimal: " + (z >>> 1) + ", binary: "
                + s.substring(Integer.toBinaryString(z >>> 1).length()) + Integer.toBinaryString(z >>> 1));
        System.out.println("z >>> 2 in decimal: " + (z >>> 2) + ", binary: "
                + s.substring(Integer.toBinaryString(z >>> 2).length()) + Integer.toBinaryString(z >>> 2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
z in decimal: -16,              binary: 11111111111111111111111111110000
z >>> 1 in decimal: 2147483640, binary: 01111111111111111111111111111000
z >>> 2 in decimal: 1073741820, binary: 00111111111111111111111111111100
```

Comment: But java uses signed numbers. And I filled the trailing positions with zeros.

Comment: Why Integer. I was using Byte

Comment: You were using byte, until you applied >>> to it and it got promoted to int.

Comment: Ahh ok. Did not know that >>> is not defined for bytes. Thanks :))